# Is there an Octave equivalent to the function "steervec"

Tags: matlab, octave

I'm searching for a way to calculate the steering vector for a delay-sum beamformer based on the position of my microphones (4) and the angle of the signal (DOA).

In matlab there is the steervec function that seems to do this. But it doesn't exist in Octave. Is there an equivalent implemented or do i have to write my own function?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `steervec` is part of the [Matlab Phased Array System Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/help/phased/ref/steervec.html) and has not yet been implemented in Octave (current release 6.2.0).  The help document lists the algorithm references for the function. If you do implement your own compatible function, I’m sure the Octave project would appreciate if you made the code available through a [missing function bug report](https://bugs.octave.org).